# Make HttpRequest With Certificates

Tags: c#, web-services, certificate, vpn, access-denied

So, I have a VPN connection with web-service provider. I was also provided `.cer` and `.pfx` files. I have installed .cer on my local machine. Now I am trying to download the `WSDL` file but whenever I make an `HttpRequest` I get 403 (Access Denied).

```
X509Certificate Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("path");
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
Request.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);
Request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

Is there any problem with my implementation?

BTW, why do I need to `.pfx`? Is not only `.Cer` file sufficient to make a request?

**UPDATE**

```
X509Certificate Cert = new X509Certificate();
Cert.Import(@"test.pfx", "123456", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

Comment: To ask the obvious, are you specifying https as the protocol for the URL you are invoking?

Comment: Also, have you installed the private/public keypair in your certificate store? The private key will be used to generate a hash during the SSL handshake. The server will verify that hash using the public key in the certificate you present. That way the server can know with certainty that you are in possession of the private key and not someone who got hold of the public certificate and are trying to impersonate. I.e. this is the reason why you need the .pfx file - you need to install it into your certificate store.

Comment: Does the same URL work in your web browser?

Comment: So, now I have installed that `.pfx` file too and attached like (see the update)

Comment: The request still ends up with 403. However now I have both of the certificates(pfx, cer) installed on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Microsoft support article.  It has code example for this and a couple different ways of handling the certificate

[How to send a client certificate by using the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes in Microsoft Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/895971?wa=wsignin1.0)

Looks like you are missing the certificate policy portion.

```
ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new CertPolicy();

//Implement the ICertificatePolicy interface.
class CertPolicy: ICertificatePolicy
{
    public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate   certificate, WebRequest request, int certificateProblem)
    {
    // You can do your own certificate checking.
    // You can obtain the error values from WinError.h.

    // Return true so that any certificate will work with this sample.
    return true;
    }
}
```

Also make sure the path to the cer file is correct and that you downloaded it using Internet explorer.

```
//You must change the path to point to your .cer file location. 
X509Certificate Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\mycert.cer");
```

And

Check the permissions -

> You must give the ASP.NET user account permissions to the private key for the client certificate. To give the ASP.NET user account permissions to the private key for the client certificate, use the WinHttpCertCfg.exe tool.

Comment: i think your missing the certificate policy does it work if you add that part?

Comment: No, it still does not. I have eliminated it later.

Comment: In general does .pfx needs to be installed as well?

Comment: See comment under question regarding .pfx file being needed

Comment: Based on the microsoft kb you dont need the pfx file.  'Method 1 is easier to use, but method requires that you have a .cer file. If you do not have the .cer file installed, use Microsoft Internet Explorer to export the .cer file.'

Comment: The .pfx is not needed at runtime but he would need to use it to install the private/public keypair to his certificate store, since from the question it is stated that he did not generate the initial private / public keypair but rather they were provided to him.

Comment: Right, it both of them were provided. I did install both of them and now I am trying to make a httprequest which ends up 403.

Comment: @user469104 - yup got you.  Could be permissions then - You must give the ASP.NET user account permissions to the private key for the client certificate. To debug you could try changing the account the IIS pool as running with...